# PhoneGap issue, need restart twice after reinstall for href state links to work?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm having an issue with my PhoneGap app, where I need to restart my app twice after a fresh install before my state change click events are firing.

I'm using Angularjs with Ionic Framework.

It seems to be isolated to "href="#/app/mystate" links in my templates.

Strangely if I restart the app twice, it works perfectly opening the third time.

It behaves identically on iOS and Android.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is quite possible that the link (template) takes time to load. My guess is that when you start the app for the first time there is nothing in the **Cache**. When you restart, it uses the files stored from the cache to load the page. You can check the cache size in Apps section of the mobile.

Comment: Thanks Frank. That would make a lot of sense. I will try preloading all the templates to see if it helps.